# python program freezes after client connects

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, flask, mjpeg

I have this python program which uses flask for video streaming( sequence of independent JPEG pictures). I know I should debug this myself first but as soon as the client connects index.html only shows a broken image icon and the computer freezes. 
I have tried -

- Running it on linux where it runs fine.
- disabling or enabling threading but it has no effect.

**edit 2** :

It worked on Linux because it had python 2.7 installed. In python 3 it doesn't show any error but doesn't work. Tried it on four systems(both windows and linux) and it seems to be a compatibility problem because it failed on all computers with python 3 but not with python 2.How can it be made to work in python 3?

**edit 1** : The freezing has been fixed by adding `time.sleep(1)` inside the loop in `gen()` but there is still no output in the browser.Recorded the network activity in chrome developer tools. Here's a screenshot - 
[image]

Here is the code :

app.py(server)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

# emulated camera
from camera import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=False)
```

camera.py

```
from time import time
class Camera(object):
    """An emulated camera implementation that streams a repeated sequence of
    files 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg at a rate of one frame per second."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.frames = [open(f + '.jpg', 'rb').read() for f in ['1', '2', '3']]

    def get_frame(self):
        return self.frames[int(time()) % 3]
```

index.py(client)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

As I have already mentioned I can't use a debugger because the whole computer freezes immediately.python version - 3.5 and os - windows 10.
 How can I fix it?

Comment: Try debugging by replacing `while True` with `for i in range(10)`. Does it still freeze then? Also, shouldn't there be a `time.sleep(1)` after each frame if you are streaming a frame per second?

Comment: @zvone it doesn't freeze now thanks but still there's no output.Just a broken image icon.

Comment: @zvone also added time.sleep(1) but still no change.

Comment: Your comment in the code says `at a rate of one frame per second` and `get_frame` returns the same image for a whole second. Anyway, it is understandable that an infinite loop with no `sleep`s freezes the computer (perhaps linux is better at managing the resources). But I don't know why this would display images in linux and not in windows... Try examining the date returned from `get_frame`.

Comment: @zvone I got confused. I am streaming at a rate of one frame per second.

Comment: Without `sleep`, you are streaming as many frames as you computer can handle, but `get_frame` creates the same frame over and over again until a second has passed. Add `print(time())` to `get_frame` to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might want to double check the routes to the image files from app.py, i.e. make sure they're in the same directory or if they're in an /images directory, double check the path to the files or that they are there to begin with.

As a test, (git) clone Miguel's project and run it and see whether you get the same result.

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

Comment: Tried cloning but still the browser shows broken image icon.